# Mining for dates with HLOOKUP-formula

Tags: google-sheets, lookup

I have a google sheet where I need to, i think, use the HLOOKUP-function. I do not however have enough knowledge to make it happen.

I have a huge sheet, where I would like to collect a start date, from "SW" or "SWF".
In the cells B2:HB2 I have dates correctly formatted.
In the cells B5:HB5 I have text with "SW", "W", "SWF" and "WF".

If the formula finds "SW" or "SWF" I would like it to give the date on the same column. 
So if the formula finds "SW" in cell D5, i would like it to show me the date in D2.

I hope someone has knowledge to make this formula and help me understand it =)

A copy, where the green area is what I hope to achieve in cell HC and HD. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wTShC1l-5PHMVeObnJQuwX1zJ4WKhJ3Vmh0hYAXo1eg/edit?usp=sharing

SW: Start Work
W: Work
SWF: Start Work Finish
WF: Work Finish

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet, excluding private or confidential information, and include an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: Here you go;
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wTShC1l-5PHMVeObnJQuwX1zJ4WKhJ3Vmh0hYAXo1eg/edit?usp=sharing

In the cells HC and HD you can see what I would like to achieve automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start: `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW($B$2),match("SW",A5:HB5,0)))`

Finish: `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW($B$2),match("SWF",A5:HB5,0)))`

---

I don't think that `HLOOKUP` (or any type of Lookup) is the correct function, since those functions focus on the value in th3e left-most column of the evaluation range.

In this answer, there are three functions used:

- `INDIRECT`
- `ADDRESS`
- `MATCH`

**Search for "SW"**
**Getting the Column**: 
`match("SW",A5:HB5,0)`: the match function "returns the relative position of an item in a range that matches a specified value." In this case, it returns the column number in which "SW" was found.

**Getting the Row**: `ADDRESS(ROW($B$2)`: all the relevant dates are in row 2, and this value can be retruned by evaluating the row in which cell B2 is found.

**Getting the date**: `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW($B$2),match("SW",A5:HB5,0)))` combines the column for the row, and returns the value found at that address.

Comment: Ah, this did the trick way easier. Thank you very much, Tedinoz!

Answer (score 1):

One drawback of the `HLOOKUP()` function is that "the first row in the range" is used to match the key. In other words, your date row should be part of the range in `HLOOKUP()` **BUT** it must be **UNDER THE FIRST ROW** in the range.

So my advice would be to move the date column to under all your names. Or make a copy of it under your names, so as not to lose readability.

Further reading: [HLOOKUP()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093375?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you. I can make a copy of the dates at the botton, this being in row 83. How does the formula look? Being sort of a noob in formulas, the help-page did not help me a lot unfortunately.<br>Never mind, I found it. Thanks!